# Pygame - all objects are drawn to the same location

Tags: python, class, pygame

i have a class to draw objects on the screen

My Class:

```
class Sword():
    def __init__(self, image, rect, speed, center):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = rect
        self.rect.x,self.rect.y = center #set x and y position
        self.speed = speed
        self.alive = True

    def live(self, enemy): #check if the image touches any object
        if self.rect.colliderect(enemy):
            self.alive = False
            mixer.music.play()

    def update(self): #move object
        self.rect.x += self.speed

    def draw(self, surface): #display object
       if self.alive:
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect))
```

---

and i tried to add few objects using a loop:

```
extend = []#object array
liste = [100,200,300]#object points x and y    
image= pygame.image.load('sword.png')
rect = image.get_rect()

for i in range(3):
    extend.append(Sword(image,rect,1,(liste[i],liste[i])))

while True:
    for tile in extend:
        tile.draw(display)
```

and inside my main loop I called this list but it drew all the images based on the last position **`Exp:rect<300,300,120,40>`**

Why does it draw all objects in the same location?

Comment: What is `sword.get_rect()`?

Comment: getting the rect of the picture exp: rect<x,y,w,h>

Comment: But what is `sword`?

Comment: I'm making a game using the pygame module and the Sword class draws something on the screen

Comment: Yes, I see that `Sword` is a class. What is `sword`?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake there,actually it should have been image.get_rect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `rect` is a single object, so as you update it the last coordinates win. You need to make a copy:

```py
from copy import copy

rect = image.get_rect()

for i in range(3):
    extend.append(Sword(image,copy(rect),1,(liste[i],liste[i])))
```

In your `Sword` class you keep updating the `x` and `y` attributes of the same instance:

```py
        self.rect = rect
        self.rect.x,self.rect.y = center #set x and y position
```

The `rect` is the same instance: the one from `image.get_rect()`.

Comment: your solution worked but I still don't understand where I went wrong I never updated the rect variable

Comment: @Django You did `self.rect.x,self.rect.y = center`, altering the rectangle object that `rect` also refers to.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for explaining,so i went crazy all night, where is my code c++ looks like:=)